Can't get Swift picker to display selected choice
I can't for the life of me figure out why my first picker is not changing. It is stuck displaying "Option A" always no matter what I pick. The other pickers work just fine.
struct ShoppingListToolView: View {
    @State private var selectedOption: Option? = nil
    @State private var selectedDuration: Duration? = nil
    @State private var selectedFrequency: Frequency? = nil

    var options: [Option] {
        return [
            Option(title: "Option A", durations: [.short, .medium]),
            Option(title: "Option B", durations: [.short, .medium]),
            Option(title: "Option C", durations: [.short, .medium]),
            Option(title: "Option D", durations: [.short, .medium]),
            Option(title: "Option E", durations: [.short, .medium]),
            Option(title: "Option F", durations: [.long]),
            Option(title: "Option G", durations: [.short]),
            Option(title: "Option H", durations: [.medium, .long]),
            Option(title: "Option I", durations: [.short, .medium, .long])
        ]
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            VStack {
                Form {
                    Section {
                        Picker(selection: $selectedOption, label: Text(selectedOption?.title ?? "Select Option")) {
                            ForEach(options) { option in
                                Text(option.title).tag(option as Option?)
                            }
                        }
                        .pickerStyle(MenuPickerStyle())
                    }
                    
                    if let selectedOption = selectedOption {
                        Section {
                            Picker("Duration", selection: $selectedDuration) {
                                ForEach(selectedOption.durations, id: \.self) { duration in
                                    Text(duration.rawValue).tag(duration as Duration?)
                                }
                            }
                            .pickerStyle(MenuPickerStyle())
                        }
                        
                        Section {
                            Picker("Frequency", selection: $selectedFrequency) {
                                ForEach(Frequency.allCases, id: \.self) { frequency in
                                    Text(frequency.rawValue).tag(frequency as Frequency?)
                                }
                            }
                            .pickerStyle(MenuPickerStyle())
                        }
                    }
                }
                
                if let selectedOption = selectedOption,
                   let selectedDuration = selectedDuration,
                   let selectedFrequency = selectedFrequency {
                    VStack {
                        Text("You selected: \(selectedOption.title)")
                            .font(.headline)
                        Text("Duration: \(selectedDuration.rawValue)")
                        Text("Frequency: \(selectedFrequency.rawValue)")
                    }
                    .padding()
                }
                
                Spacer()
            }
            .navigationTitle("Tool")
            .background(Color.green.opacity(0.3).edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all))
        }
    }
    
    struct Option: Identifiable, Hashable {
        let id = UUID()
        let title: String
        let durations: [Duration]
    }
    
    enum Duration: String, CaseIterable, Hashable {
        case short = "Short"
        case medium = "Medium"
        case long = "Long"
    }
    
    enum Frequency: String, CaseIterable, Hashable {
        case daily = "Daily"
        case weekly = "Weekly"
        case monthly = "Monthly"
    }
}

I tried to make it so that when something is selected the blue picker text changes to that which was selected. What actually happens is it just continually displays "Option A" but the other pickers react to the correct selection. So it has selected it correctly but just isn't displaying it correctly in that initial picker.

The issue is that you've created bindings that aren't actually equatable. If you use selectedOption, the Picker can't actually compare it because the Option struct doesn't conform to Equatable. Set up the struct to conform like this:
struct Option: Identifiable, Hashable, Equatable {
        let id = UUID()
        let title: String
        let durations: [Duration]

        static func == (lhs: Option, rhs: Option) -> Bool {
            return lhs.id == rhs.id
        }
}


The cause of your problem is because you are using a computed property
var options: [Option] {...}.
Try using
let options: [Option] = [...]
instead, works for me.
If in future you need to add to the options, then declare it as a @State...,
if not, declare it as a let.
